# how to copy mongodb data from local to virtual machine?

Tags: mongodb

I got an application from my developer and he asked me to host it over intranet. When i try to host it from virtual machine(cloud server), the mongo db data are missing from the collections.

Steps followed to host a site:
Copied the nodejs application folder from local to virtual machine.
Gave ng build followed by NPM start.
Now the mongodb connection is opened and able to see my database but the collections are empty.

Can anyone suggest me how to backup/copy the mongo db data from local to VM?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think MongoDB backup/restore will help
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/

from your local

```
mongodump --archive=test.20150715.gz --gzip --db test
```

move the backup file to your VM then run:

```
mongorestore --archive=test.20150715.gz --db test
```